# Visual studio 2019 and IdentityServer project template

Tags: identityserver4, visual-studio-2019

Trying to follow the tutorials for IdentityServer using Visual studio 2019.

As per the instructions created a .Net Core Web Application and then an MVC project type and as per tutorials a welcome screen for IdentityServer should come at run time
[image]

But i am getting an MVC page template only like this

[image]

Is there any difference in project templates based on new visual studio updates? Or what is the correct selection of project types to get the window similar to the first image ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running the mvc application insteed of the identity provider service.

Go to the solution properties, Common Properties, and select Multiple startup projects. Then change the Action to Start for debug all your projects.

[image]

If you prefer start only your identity provider service set it as the Single startup project.

Comment: i don't have multiple projects as of now. I only created a ASP.Net Core project

Comment: Ok, then you should create an empty mvc project for the quickstart tutorial. You shouldn't have Controllers and Views. Later you will add the mvc UI components (login, logout, consent...).

Comment: I followed the steps or commands   dotnet new is4inmem from powershell and i am getting the view as expected from the project created with the command